# Many external links affecting SEO?

Tags: seo, links, nofollow

I run a website that is for a non-profit organization and the site is mainly information for the consumer. A page on this site list stores that are a certain type of business. I am planning on adding websites to the information provided to the end user.

My question is this:

Should I `nofollow` the links to the external website? We are talking about 100+ links (and growing) on this one page. I do not want to negativity affect the SEO on my site nor on the other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to add more external links (100+) in a single page, you should use `nofollow` attributes which is more safe for your website. If you have a page with bunch of external links targetting different business means it might look odd for bot. So my opinion is using `nofollow` in this case is highly recommendated.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will play it safe and add the nofollow.